Angular : checkbox unchecked whereas value is True
In a table I have this cell :
<tr  class="table-bordered-grey table-hover-custom"  *ngFor="let missionCra of cra.missionCraDtos; let i = index" triggers="click:blur">
   <td *ngFor="let detailCra of missionCra.detailsCraDtos" class="centered">
      <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="detailCra.ttMatin" name="ttMatin" >
   </td>
</tr>

detailCra.ttMatin is True , but the checkbox is not checked.
I am loading cra in the ngOnInit :
ngOnInit() {
        this.loadCra();
}
loadCra() {
        this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ cra }) => {
            this.cra = cra;
        });
}

Any idea of why the checkbox keeps being unchecked?

Check if you have an error in console (F12 in the navigator), the code looks like ok. Check also if you have no spell error (the variables have different names or one is upper case and the other lower case)
